# minko get object from dom

Tags: javascript, minko

I create an object in my javascript function, and I'd want to retrieve it in c++ from dom class for change some values, but I can access only by id, tag or class that are part of css syntax. Is there the possibility to get my object and set values or send to him those value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should always get DOM elements by id or class name because IMHO it's the most versatile way to get things from this kind of tree.

Anyway, just like any other DOM Minko provides the [childNodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) and [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentNode.asp) properties if you want/have to browse the tree :

- [AbstractDOM::childNodes()](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/plugin/html-overlay/include/minko/dom/AbstractDOMElement.hpp#L69)
- [AbstractDOM::parentNode()](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/plugin/html-overlay/include/minko/dom/AbstractDOMElement.hpp#L65)

When you've found the right DOM element, you can then use the other DOM methods to get its content, set its value, etc... Everything you need should be in the [AbstractDOM base class definition](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/plugin/html-overlay/include/minko/dom/AbstractDOMElement.hpp).

Comment: thanks! let's suppose I have create in my js an object. How can I add or bind  it to the dom and so retrieve it in that way?

Comment: That's another question. StackOverflow etiquette is to create a separate question for each well... separate question :) And if my answer is ok for your first question, please mark it as such.

Comment: done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206609/binding-of-a-dom-element-to-a-javascript-variable