# Binding of a dom element to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

I'm new to js and my task is this:
I've to bind a gauge object like one you can download from this rep:
https://github.com/Mikhus/canv-gauge.git

to a dom element in order to get it from c++ software.
How can I create my var and set it with id, just to use GetElementFromId dom method?

thank you,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with jQuery.

Here is the example:

```
var elt = document.getElementById('dom-id');
jQuery.data(elt, "gauge", gaugeObject);
```

Be careful that the first argument of `jQuery.data()` is a DOM object,
instead of a jQuery object.

When you want to get the binded object, use

```
var gaugeObject = jQuery.data(elt, "gauge");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact between JavaScript code and a host C++ app (like an app built with V8, CEF or [Minko](http://github.com/aerys/minko)), you can:

- call eval from the C++ host (for example Minko provides the [AbstractDOM::eval()](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/plugin/html-overlay/include/minko/dom/AbstractDOM.hpp#L42) method) using the code provided by cipher
- call methods specific to the C++ host implementation, for example Minko provides a two-way C++/JS messaging system described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930210/is-it-possible-to-trigger-c-code-intiated-by-html-events-in-minko/28931025?noredirect=1#comment46159246_28931025)